# Record and "playback" css 3d transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-transforms, jquery-events

I'm trying to record a user's mouse and key inputs, then "play them back" to the user by triggering events at chronologically the same time they occurred.  That sentence is a little confusing so I'll explain my code:

```
var $dancerContainer = $('.dancerContainer');

var count = 3;  
var captured;
var countInterval;
```

`$dancerContainer` is the element I want to animate, which is a div.
`count` is the duration of the 'recording' phase.
`captured` will eventually be an object that holds the events, keyed by the elapsed time in milliseconds they occurred since the start of the recording.

```
function captureInput() {
  var mouseCapture = [];
  var keyCapture = [];
  var start = new Date().getTime();

$(document).on('mousemove.capture', function(event) {
  event.t = new Date().getTime() - start;
  mouseCapture.push(event);
});

$(document).on('keyup.capture', function(event) {
  event.t = new Date().getTime() - start;
  keyCapture.push(event);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).off('.capture');
  captured = chronoCaptures(mouseCapture, keyCapture);
}, 3000);
}
```

The `captureInput` func tags an elapsed time on the event before pushing them to mouse and keyup arrays, `mouseCapture` and `keyCapture`, then unbinds the listeners.

```
function chronoCaptures(mouse, keyboard) {
  var greater = (mouse.length > keyboard.length) ? mouse.length : keyboard.length;
  var chrono = {};
  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < greater; i++) {
    if (keyboard[k] == undefined) {
      chrono[mouse[j].t] = mouse[j];
      j++; 
    } else if (mouse[j] == undefined) {
      chrono[keyboard[k].t] = keyboard[k];
      k++; 
    } else {
      if (mouse[j].t < keyboard[k].t) {
        chrono[mouse[j].t] = mouse[j];
        j++;
      } else {
        chrono[keyboard[k].t] = keyboard[k];
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
  return chrono;
}
```

`chronoOrderCaptures` then takes the two arrays of events and returns an object whose keys are the times each event occurred. Now that I look at this code again, since I'm putting the events into an object anyway, it doesn't matter what order they get put in.  I might overwrite an event with another, in which case I want the key event to take precedence (going to refactor this, but this is beside the point).

```
function replayDance(captured, duration) {
  var d = duration * 1000;
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsed = 0;
  while (elapsed <= d) {
    elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    var c = captured[elapsed];
    if (c) { 
      $dancerContainer.trigger(c)
    }
  }

}
```

Finally, `replayDance` waits for the duration of the recording and checks how much time has elapsed. If the `captured` object contains an entry @ that amount of elapsed time, I trigger the event on the document.

WHEW. Thank you if you've gotten this far. Now to the problem!! (what?) The problem I'm having is the mouse events all get played back 'at once'.  There's no pausing occurring, I don't see them executed in sequence as if I was actually moving the mouse, although it seems like they ought to be getting triggered at roughly the same time they were recorded.

Finally here is the handler for `mousemove` events:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', followMouse);

function followMouse(event) {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  var mouseX = event.pageX - (width * 0.25);
  var mouseY = event.pageY - (height * 0.25);
  var angleX = (mouseY / height) * 45;
  var angleY = (mouseX / width) * 45;
  dancer.style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(" + angleX + "deg) rotateY(" + angleY + "deg)";       
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely not the right way to wait for a period of time. You're going to set people's computers on fire.

Comment: Just use [`setTimeout(function() {...}, milliseconds)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) to delay execution of any JavaScript code.

Comment: Now that you point it out, that loop seems insane to me.  Thank you, actually I realize I can just push all events to an array and forget the time-key object.